# CRM 2011 - SQL Query to retrieve text of option set?

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to write the query to retrieve the data from the Contact table. So, let us say I want the following fields

FirstName, LastName and Gender.

Now, the field for gender is gendercode, which is an option set and this data resides in StringMapBase.

What would the query to return the text value of gendercode?

I could write this, but surely there is a better way to write.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, GenderCode FROM Contact
```

For retrieving the text value

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, GenderCode, sm.Value as Gender FROM Contact c, StringMap sm
WHERE c.GenderCode = sm.AttributeValue
AND sm.AttributeName = 'gendercode'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's wrong with your current query? it looks to be correct

Comment: Yes, I have a suggestion. Use the SDK API and don't touch the DDBB! It's an unsupported customization!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928224.aspx

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but was wondering if it can be written better? For instance, if the Contact table is to be joined with another table which has an option set then I would be joining with StringMap again, which makes the query look dangerous to an audience who have been used to writing simple queries.

Comment: @Oscar: Thanks, but this is for the reporting people. I am not going to be writing anything, but just reading values. People, who will read the data through SSRS (I am not a reporting guy, so no idea about that).

Comment: The fact is that Microsoft can change the DDBB schema and leave your customization useless, while they warrant the API to be unchanged.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But, even if this is not related to CRM 2011, if we had a DB structure like this...how would a query be written?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [filtered views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa681857.aspx) for reading from the DB.  Fully supported and gives you what you need without jumping through hoops and creating joins.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, gendercodename from FilteredContact
```

Comment: +1 because you posted 8 seconds before me, and is useless to write the same query twice :)